# Can someone explain this please? This code gives me an output but it does not make any sense to me

Tags: python

```
numbers = [2, 3, 4, 5]
for index in range(len(numbers)):
    numbers[index] = numbers[index] ** 2
```

> numbers [4, 9, 16, 25]

Ok, so this simple little code is from a text book that I have been reading to learn Python. Unfortunately the book does not provide any explanation therefore I am unable to understand the concept here. Let me share what I know and understand.

So we create a list of four integers and store it in a variable. Next, in the second line we add another variable 'index', as far as I know, you can add any variable here, If I were to write Apples instead of index it would still work. But when we say, "for index in range(len(numbers))" why did we put the len function here? I tried without the len function and it gave a TypeError but why do we have to put len here? Why can't we write "for index in numbers"? I tried that and it gave an IndexError.

And then in the next line "numbers[index] = numbers[index] ** 2", why did we put index in square brackets in the first half? I have not been able to make any sense of this, can someone please explain the logic behind this? The end result is a square of each integer which is fine but how do you explain the code? I'd appreciate your input thanks.

Comment: These are very fundamental questions, and this question therefore lacks focus. I would suggest some [reading](https://www.python.org/doc/).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I know that this is your first question but I would suggest you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: It seems like you want to understand what [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) does, and how to [index into lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists). Try adding the line: `print("at index: ", index, " number is: ", numbers[index])` after the `for` line.

Comment: Since you are pretty new to coding I would suggest taking some online courses on Youtube or any other platform and understanding the basic fundamentals of Python programming. I have suggested some videos on my profile.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer your questions one by one:

> why did we put the len function here

The len() function gets the length of the `numbers` array.

Since the code uses `range()`, an number must be passed in to this function, and `len` helps get this number. Read more about the range function [here](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/range.html).

> Why can't we write "for index in numbers"?

There is nothing stopping you from doing this. This is a perfectly valid syntax. The error you get is actually from the next line since `index` is no longer the actual index, but a value from the array.

Earlier, the index would have gone  `1, 2, 3`, but now the index holds the array values and goes `2, 3, 4, 5`.

> why did we put index in square brackets in the first half?

As suggested by the comments, the best way to understand this is to try it yourself by printing out the `numbers[index]` and seeing what the output is.

Answer (score -1):

In Python, the range() function returns a range object, which is a sequence of numbers that represent a starting value, a stopping value, and a stepping value. Out of these three parameters, only the stop value is required.

```py
range(len(numbers)):
```

In your case, this will return a range object from 0 to 4 - note that the stopping value is never actually used itself, so the for loop, in reality, will go through 0, 1, 2, and 3. This also happens to be all the valid indexes for your numbers list.

numbers[index] gets the number at position [index] of numbers. For example, numbers[0] is the first number in the list. index is replaced with 0, 1, 2, then 3, according to the for loop.

I reccomend looking up some basic Python guides, either text or video; many can be foundon YouTube.

Answer (score -2):

this particular script gives you the square of each number in the list.
if you edit it to read

```
numbers = [2, 3, 4, 5]
for index in range(len(numbers)):
    print(numbers[index], numbers[index]**2)
    numbers[index] = numbers[index] ** 2
```

you get the following output :

```
2 4
3 9
4 16
5 25
```

For numeric data types double asterisk (**) is defined as exponentiation operator.

In a function definition, argument with double asterisks as prefix helps in sending multiple keyword arguments to it from calling environment.

[Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-does-the-Double-Star-operator-mean-in-Python)

Comment: This strikes me as wholly inadequate as an answer, but that's to be expected as the OP needs a beginner's tutorial and not a SO answer.